# I seek a PDF paginator

Tags: pdf

More precisely, I need software that will allow me to consume existing PDF instances, decorate them with page numbers, or page-number-like writing, then write them back to the filesystem.  I'll happily pay for an application, or program it myself.  I almost certainly require the software run under Linux (Ubuntu, more specifically).

iText comes close.  iText certainly can read existing PDF instances.  While iText is, for this purpose, only a library, and requires me to program a tiny amount to specify where on the page the numbers should appear, I'm happy to do that.  I hesitate with iText only because the latest iText license is a headache at certain government agencies (in practice, I'd probably request and pay for a special license), and because, over the last few years, I've observed cases where iText doesn't appear to keep up with the standard, that is, it has more troubles than I expect reading PDFs observed "in the wild".

Similarly, every other possibility I know has at least one difficulty:  ReportLab would likely require a disproportionate licensing fee for the small value it provides in this situation, and so on.

This application requires no particular sophistication with Unicode, fonts, ...

I recognize there are plenty of executables and libraries that do some or all of what I require.  I welcome any tips on software that is

- reliable,

  generally current with PDF practice,

  flexible/programmable/configurable/..., and

  "automatable".

In the absence of any new insight, I'll likely go with a specific open-source library I don't want to mention now for which I've already contracted enhancements, or perhaps revisit iText.

Comment: I'm unsure but looking at pdftk might be useful ( http://www.accesspdf.com/pdftk/ )

Comment: Briefly, pdftk is a dead end.  Its creator stopped supporting it.  I use pdftk, in fact, and there are tales that others will take up support of it.  For my current use, pdftk is simply too old:  it's too far behind more recent PDF definitions to recognize a sufficiently high number of the PDF instances I encounter.

I entirely agree, though, that pdftk is a valuable tool, and I use it when I can.  Thanks for the suggestion.

Answer (score 0):

You should look at http://www.accesspdf.com/pdftk/ . What you ask I believe can be easily achieved via stamping/watermarking.

Comment: Not directly. The stamping/watermarking process only allows you to use the same image on every page. I referred to that tool in a comment in case the OP wanted to look at it's source code for ideas.

Comment: Well I might agree, even if it depends on your "directly" definition :). Having prepared the pdf files with the page numbers in advance, I guess it can be done on a single bash line.

Comment: "Well I might agree ...":  I'm lost.  It sounds as though you have a single bash line that does ... "it"?  Which "it" are we talking about now?  I'll happily receive a succinct bash form that paginates PDF.  Even a single bash line that leverages pdftk to do the same will interest me.  Perhaps I misunderstand what you intend by "I guess".

Comment: @cameron-laird: pdftk allows splitting a pdf into pages, stamping each single page and joining the result in one pdf, all from the command line. The ingredients are there, building the one-liner (or a simple bash script) should then be a matter of a few tries (if you are not familiar with bash you can have a look at the Advanced Bash Scripting Guide).

Comment: Thank you for these details, baol.  Fond as I am of pdftk, its current version is unlikely to be "modern" enough for the particular project at hand.  Also, I now better understand what you mean by "[h]aving prepared ... pdf ... with the page numbers in advance ...", and "one-liner".

Thank you for the reference to Cooper's *... Guide*; it's a resource that's always pertinent.

Answer (score 0):

[This Google search](http://www.google.com/search?hl=en&ei=kSGuS_3TG4Wdlgfi_OWQAQ&sa=X&oi=spell&resnum=0&ct=result&cd=1&ved=0CBIQBSgA&q=print+page+number+pdf&spell=1) led me to [APDF Number](http://www.a-pdf.com/number/).

Comment: Thank you, BillyONeal:  while "APDF Number" doesn't appear to me to support Linux currently, it has enough desirable properties that I'll be testing it over the next week.